# Multicolumn LIST<T> - Finding duplicates of a one column based on another column

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, duplicates, duplicate-data

I need to find the duplicate items of one column (`Qty`) based on another column (`Priority`). I have a List that contains the following data:

```
Priority  Product  Qty
0           a       10
0           b       20
1           c       50
1           d       20
1           e       50
1           f       10
1           g       20
1           h       10
```

I need to produce a sorted `List<T>` that contains only the duplicates in terms of `Qty` among the items with priority `0`.

I.e. the resulting `List<T>` would contain:

```
Priority  Product  Qty
0           a       10
1           f       10
1           h       10
0           b       20
1           d       20
1           g       20
```

Is there a simple LINQ/Lambda expression for doing this?

Comment: @BartoszKP How did you put the List<T> in the text? I tried for ages to do that then gave up and posted the question without it??? Sorry to be so dumb but you would have guessed by now I'm new to this!!!

Comment: Use the reverse apostrophe sign. You can also click "edit" under your question and see exactly how I did it. You can find more information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: @BartoszKP Got it, and found it in the edit and in the link you gave. None so blind and all that. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb534501%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var result = input
    .GroupBy(p => p.Qty)
    .Where(g => g.Any(p0 => p0.Priority == 0))
    .Where(g => g.Skip(1).Any())
    .SelectMany(g => g)
    .OrderBy(g => g.Qty);
```

Comment: Thanks @BartoszKP. That seems to have done the trick nicely. Have you got any idea why I have got -1 against my question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var items = new List<Item>
    {
        new Item { Priority = 0, Product = "a", Qty = 10 },
        new Item { Priority = 0, Product = "b", Qty = 20 },
        new Item { Priority = 1, Product = "c", Qty = 50 },
        new Item { Priority = 1, Product = "d", Qty = 20 },
        new Item { Priority = 1, Product = "e", Qty = 50 },
        new Item { Priority = 1, Product = "f", Qty = 10 },
        new Item { Priority = 1, Product = "g", Qty = 20 },
        new Item { Priority = 1, Product = "h", Qty = 10 }
    };

    foreach (var group in items.Where  (i => i.Priority == 0)
                               .GroupBy(i => i, g => items
                               .Where  (t => t.Qty == g.Qty && 
                                             t.Product != g.Product)))
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine(group.Key);                   // Priority == 0
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        foreach (var item in group.SelectMany(i => i))  // dups
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", item);
    }
}

class Item
{
    public int    Priority { get; set; }
    public string Product  { get; set; }
    public int    Qty      { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}",
                             this.Priority, this.Product, this.Qty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not return a list containing the results so I'm finding it a bit difficult to test. What would need to be added to return a List<T> of the results?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an enumerable container called list that contains elements with properties Priority, Product and Qty:

```
var orderedResult = list.Where(element => !list.Contains(x => x != element && x.Priority == element.Priority && x.Qty == element.Qty)).OrderBy(element => element.Qty).ThenBy(element => element.Priority);
```